# Como importar arquivos da pasta node_modules / em meus arquivos da view?

Tags: php, javascript, html, npm, twig

Eu estou tentando aprender algumas novas tecnologias, então eu decidi experimentar o npm, baixei esses pacotes (jquery e jquery-validation) usando npm e agora estou tentando importar esses pacotes ao meu arquivo da view mas não consigo acessar qualquer fora da pasta pública.

Ja tentei importar diretamente da pasta mas não é possivel

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Deveria estar usando algum outro componente que não conheço ou há alguma maneira de tornar meus pacotes em node_modules/ acessiveis?

Aqui está a minha pasta de estrutura e alguns arquivos importantes:

- myproject

  - App

    - Controllers
    - Models
    - Views

      - Signup

        - new.html
      - base.html
  - Core
  - node_modules

    - jquery
    - jquery-validation
  - public

    - index.php(Front Controller)
  - etc...

Base.html (Estou usando twig como template engine)

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</nav>

{% block body %} 
{% endblock %}

<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

index.php

```
/**
 * Front Controller
 */

 /**
  * Composer
  */
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Error and Exception handling
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler('Core\Error::errorHandler');
set_exception_handler('Core\Error::exceptionHandler');

 /**
  * Routing
  */
$router = new Core\Router();

// Add the routes
$router->add('', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index']);
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');
//$router->add('{controller}/{id:\d+}/{action}');
//$router->add('admin/{controller}/{action}', ['namespace' => 'Admin']);

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, imagino que não seja possível utilizar diretamente da pasta node_modules tendo em vista que este não está público por questão de segurança.

**1 Solução** é utilizar o [webpack](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-ao-webpack/) e compilar em junto com seu app.js(script principal).
**2 Solução** Mova a pasta desejada para a pasta public (crie uma pasta assets para deixar organizado).